# Configuring Vim with clientserver and clipboard

Tags: vim, osx

On OS X I have vim working just fine from homebrew. The default homebrew install compiles vim with these flags.

```
./configure
  --prefix=/usr/local
  --mandir=/usr/local/Cellar/vim/7.4.161/share/man
  --enable-multibyte
  --with-tlib=ncurses
  --enable-cscope
  --with-features=huge
  --with-compiledby=Homebrew     
  --enable-rubyinterp
  --enable-pythoninterp
  --enable-gui=no
  --without-x
```

This install works perfectly with the system clipboard using this in my vimrc:

```
if has("clipboard")
    set clipboard=unnamed
endif
```

Homebrew also has flags for installing `--with-client-server` if you use this it compiles vim with:

```
./configure
  --prefix=/usr/local
  --mandir=/usr/local/Cellar/vim/7.4.161/share/man
  --enable-multibyte
  --with-tlib=ncurses
  --enable-cscope
  --with-features=huge
  --with-compiledby=Homebrew     
  --enable-rubyinterp
  --enable-pythoninterp
  --enable-gui=gtk2
```

This compiles vim with `+clientserver` and `+clipboard`. Running `set clipboard?` returns `unnamed` yet now the integration with the system clipboard does not work at all, even when prefixing commands with `"+` or `"*`.

Is there a way I can have both of these features work with a single vim install?

**EDIT:**

After some more searching I believe this is an issue on OS X with the system pasteboard not being correctly synced with the X11 server. I found a similar question [here](https://superuser.com/a/17499/143895) which gives you the settings you need to setup clipboard sync with X11. There is also a gui for that in the newer versions. [image: X11 Prefs]

Unfortunately this didn't work. I believe it's covered [here](http://xquartz.macosforge.org/trac/ticket/765) in an open bug report on the xquartz tracker. It also looks like this may have been an issue for [a while](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/187497).

Answer (score 2):

I discovered the issues here that seemed to lead to this not working. First and foremost I had a symlinked [`~/.Xdefaults`](https://github.com/Keithbsmiley/dotfiles/blob/741078607fe08e5d37aff55d914f4ac5c3fc9a26/Xdefaults) and [`~/.Xmodmap`](https://github.com/Keithbsmiley/dotfiles/blob/741078607fe08e5d37aff55d914f4ac5c3fc9a26/Xmodmap) that are just excess from using the same dotfiles on Linux distributions. While neither of these seem to mess with any clipboard settings directly, removing them seemed to matter.

Setting the pasteboard syncing options in X11 is a must. I eventually decided on these settings:

```
# Clipboard syncing
defaults write org.macosforge.xquartz.X11 sync_clipboard_to_pasteboard -boolean true
defaults write org.macosforge.xquartz.X11 sync_pasteboard -boolean true
defaults write org.macosforge.xquartz.X11 sync_pasteboard_to_clipboard -boolean true
defaults write org.macosforge.xquartz.X11 sync_pasteboard_to_primary -boolean true
defaults write org.macosforge.xquartz.X11 sync_primary_on_select -boolean false

# Run xterm by default (without this vim's clipboard doesn't work)
defaults write org.macosforge.xquartz.X11 app_to_run -string "/opt/X11/bin/xterm"

# Set default shell
defaults write org.macosforge.xquartz.X11 login_shell -string "/usr/local/bin/zsh"
```

The running xterm by default is a must. X11 does not seem to want to share its clipboard with the OS X pasteboard until xterm has been run at least once. It doesn't even have to be open, it just has to have run this session. This setting is the default for X11 but some people change it so xterm doesn't start every time they start X11. If you run vim with `+clientserver` for the first time before XQuartz/X11 has opened it will ignore this setting when it opens X11. If xterm does not run before you launch vim, the clipboards will not be synced and you will have to restart vim to fix it. I've chosen to open XQuartz by default every time I log in and hide it.

You have to setup vim's clipboard correctly. These settings work:

```
if has("clipboard")
  set clipboard=unnamed " copy to the system clipboard

  if has("unnamedplus") " X11 support
    set clipboard+=unnamedplus
  endif
endif
```

Adding `unnamedplus` to the clipboard settings uses both the `*` and `+` registers for each yank. These settings ensure that the clipboard will be set to `unnamed` if just `+clipboard` is setup and to `unnamed,unnamedplus` if you have `+xterm_clipboard`. I found this option [here](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/accessing-the-system-clipboard-from-vim/).

Then you can just install Vim via homebrew with:

```
brew install vim --with-client-server
```

Unfortunately X11 pasteboard sync still doesn't seem to work consistently so for now I have given up on this setup.

Comment: This solves my initial problem it seems, but I do wonder if you've ever gotten both to work reliably at the same time. I'm considering dropping the client-server support in exchange for the clipboard.

Comment: @Wolph this didn't solve my issue reliably. I haven't tried with the newest build of xquartz released on 2014-08-18

Comment: I've tried for a bit using the new XQuartz release and I haven't seen any clipboard issues. But it did break the syntax highlighting partially (underlines instead of highlighting when selecting for example) so I've switched to a non-gtk (i.e. without client-server) version of Vim which generally works better. I'll miss the client-server support but I can work around it by controlling tmux from Vim.